# Изображение точек в 3D по координатам

Tags: windows, графика, opengl

Добрый день!

Есть вопрос. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изобразить точки, которые заданы массивом координат (х,y,z). Необходимо вывести точки на экран (или вместо точек выводить маленькие шарики).

Вычисление координат сделано в Visual Studio 2010 в Win32 Console application.
Есть и другой вариант - выводить на экран небольшие окружности с центрами в заданных точках с помощью OpenGL. Но не знаю, как работать с OpenGL.

Поделитесь опытом. -)

Comment: Здравствуйте. Я бы вам посоветовал использовать не OpenGL, а SDL. http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php

Answer (score 1):

В студии очень просто сделать через XNA: [взаимодействие 3D объектов](http://www.xnadev.ru/articles.php?article_id=93).

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL на уровне, который вам понадобится, очень прост. Посмотрите библиотеку glut (она как раз ориентирована на консольные приложения и содержит готовые функции отрисовки простых поверхностей типа сфер). Точки можно отображать сферами малого радиуса.
Весь код отображения и инициализации глюта займет у вас строк 10. А вот директХ конкретно в данном случае не стал бы использовать - он крайне нелаконичен.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, зачем вам OpenGL, я сам раньше писал под DirectX. Если вам нужно просто спроецировать точки в пространстве на плоскость экрана, то вам нужно определиться под каким углом вы хотите их видеть, а затем умножить векторы точек на матрицу вращения (например, вокруг оси Y).

```
 cosΐ  0  -sinΐ   0

 0     1     0    0

 sinΐ  0   cosΐ   0

 0     0     0    1
```

Подробнее читайте тут: [матрица поворота](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0).

Comment: Если вам нужна информация про то, как именно выводить точки, то можете прочитать, например, тут: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff729719(v=VS.85).aspx#Elements_of_a_Triangle (для Direct3D 11), http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee418890(v=VS.85).aspx (для Direct3D 9).

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!